# Can you "cache" matplotlib plots and show them dynamically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create some matplotlib plots in batch, and then display them interactively, e.g something like this? (current code doesn't display the plots)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact
plots = {'a': plt.plot([1,1],[1,2]), 'b': plt.plot([2,2],[1,2])}

def f(x):
    return plots[x]

interact(f, x=['a','b'])
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output here? `plt.plot` returns a list of lines. A line needs to be part of a matplotlib figure to be shown.

Comment: So the desired output is an interactive widget where i can switch between two figures without "redrawing" them from scratch. is this possible?

Comment: A figure needs to be redrawn to be shown on screen.

Comment: ok so am i best off just exporting to png then displaying these? (context is i have some plots which take 30s to render)

Comment: I cannot say what would be best, because the question is very generic. So I gave a very generic answer below.

Answer (score 3):

#### Redraw figure

Possibly you want something like this, where the figure is cleared on each new selection and the artist in question is readded to the canvas.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact
plots = {'a': plt.plot([1,1],[1,2]), 'b': plt.plot([2,2],[1,2])}

def f(x):
    plt.gca().clear()
    plt.gca().add_artist(plots[x][0])
    plt.gca().autoscale()
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()

interact(f, x=['a','b']);
```

Result in a jupyter notebook:

[image]

#### Blitting

Unfortunately, the notebook backend currently [does not support blitting](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4288). Using blitting, one could build the the plots beforehands and then just blit them to the axes. This could look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.18)
line1, = ax.plot([1,1],[1,2])
line2, = ax.plot([2,2],[1,2], color="crimson")
line2.remove()
fig.canvas.draw()
# store state A, where line1 is present
stateA = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

line1.remove()
ax.add_artist(line2)
fig.canvas.draw()
# store state B, where line2 is present
stateB = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)


plots = {'a': stateA, 'b': stateB}
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
check = RadioButtons(rax, ('a', 'b'), (False, True))

def f(x):
    fig.canvas.restore_region(plots[x])
    
check.on_clicked(f)

plt.show()
```

The above runs fine in an normal interactive figure. Once blitting is supported in the notebook backend in some future version of matplotlib, one could replace the `RadioButtons` and use `interact` in a notebook.